# Activating/Using ISim tool chain with Eclipse (VHDL)

Tags: eclipse, vhdl, toolchain, xilinx-ise, sigasi-studio

I'm attempting to program very basic VHDL on eclipse using the Sigasi plugin with an educational license - with the aim to be, I can program a simple entity and a test bench for it, then compile and simulate it in Xilinx's ISim.

I have installed Eclipse, Sigasi & Xilinx ISE Webpack, and have attempted to add the ISim toolchain to Eclipse as shown in the Sigasi website [here](http://www.sigasi.com/screencast/integration-xilinx-isim-hdl-simulator)

It appears okay but it says I need to "activate" the toolchain (as shown below)
[image: first window]

However, when I follow the "click here to activate now", I get taken to the scree below - from which nothing happens. If I click Apply, nothing happens, there's no further options!

[image: second window]

My question - how do I actually configure ISim to launch from Eclipse, is what I want to do actually possible or have I misunderstood and if so, how do I do it.

Thanks very much for your help!

David

Comment: Take a look at Sigasi's [Tool Integration](http://doc.sigasi.com/manual/8_tools.html) Integration page - *For some toolchains you can specify extra command line arguments* under [Configure external compiler](http://doc.sigasi.com/manual/8_tools.html), the second [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EMkh3.png) showing Sigasi preferences.

Comment: But I'm using the Xilinx toolchain (or attempting too) and theres no options to add extra command line arguments to it...? (As shown in the first image in the question)

Comment: There's also Sigasi **Run** ->  **External Tools** -> **External Tool Configurations** which allows *you to allow you to configure and run programs, batch files, Ant buildfiles and others using the Workbench. You can save these external tool configurations and run them at a later time.* (From Sigasi Help). You can put anything in a batch file, and select it to run, organize the order your batch files show up,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable the ISim toolchain, Sigasi will automatically compile your files with ISim when you save your files. You can check the output in the *Console View*

To start a simulation, you need to set a top-level first. You can do this in the *Hierarchy View*. Next, click on the *Simulate* button.

You can find more details in the [Sigasi Studio manual](http://insights.sigasi.com/manual/tools.html#launch-simulator)